# How to simulate mouse click/key stroke to choose how many listings per page in Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, headless-browser

I have difficulty to simulate the mouse click/key stroke to choose how many lists per page after `page.goto()`. Here is the HTML source code for the `per page` option:

```
<label class="control-label pull-right" style="margin-right: 10px; font-weight: 100;">
    <small>Show</small>&nbsp;
    <select class="input-sm grid-per-pager" name="per-page">
        <option value="https://www.mysite-com/admin/order?per_page=10" >10</option>
        <option value="https://www.mysite-com/admin/order?per_page=20" selected>20</option>
        <option value="https://www.mysite-com/admin/order?per_page=30" >30</option>
        <option value="https://www.mysite-com/admin/order?per_page=50" >50</option>
        <option value="https://www.mysited-com/admin/order?per_page=100" >100</option>
    </select>
    &nbsp;<small>Piece</small>
</label>
```

The default is `20` listings per page, and I would like to change it to `100` listings per page which requires mouse click the box and hit down arrow key twice to choose `100`. Here is some code for the purpose:

```
await page.mouse.click("label.control-label .grid-per-pager");
await page.keyboard.press("ArrowDown");
await page.keyboard.press("ArrowDown");
```

It gave me a few errors. What is missing here?

Comment: `It gave me a few errors` Please edit the question to add those errors. Given how little info we have those errors could be what could help resolve the issue.

Comment: Anyway, do you `waitForSelector` before interacting with selectbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### page.select()

The best method to use in this case is [`page.select()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageselectselector-values).

This method accepts the selector for the `select` element as the first parameter and the `value` of the `option` you would like to select as the second parameter:

```
await page.select('select[name="per-page"]', 'https://www.mysited-com/admin/order?per_page=100');
```